# Next.jS SSG on s3bucket doesn't work on refresh

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, next.js13, cdn, nx-monorepo

I need help with deployment of the Next.js SSG on s3bucket.

I have a **Next.js (v: "13.4.9") nx monorepo** app, with these config settings:

```
output: 'export',
distDir: 'dist',
trailingSlash: true,
experimental: { appDir: true },
```

When I navigate through the app everything is **fine**, but If I try to **refresh** the page, error 404 appears.

To me it seems like I am trying to access /about/ but the page is actually on /about/**index.html**.
When I add /page/index.html manually - everything works great again.

I thought I understood correctly next.js documentation, that the **trailingSlash: true,** property should **fix** that problem but it's not happening.

I tried adding **index.html** programaticaly for links when the code is on server, but the **html** part simply dissapears from the url... So that wasn't epected at all.

What else could be the problem? Is experimental: { appDir: true } causing problems for Next.js (v: "13.4.9") ?
How can I fix this problem?
Is anyone having an idea why **.html** part disappears just like that?